# How to add gripper to robot arm and plan according to the end effector on Moveit

Tags: simulation, manipulator, moveit, gripper, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am simulating for a university project, the Elfin 5 robot arm which package can be found [here](https://github.com/hans-robot/elfin_robot/tree/noetic) along with a gripper which package is found [here](https://github.com/juandpenan/onrobot_2FG7_gripper_description).
Being new to Moveit, I am finding trouble to attach the gripper to the robot to be able to control it and plan accordingly.

Looking at the robot's [URDF](https://github.com/hans-robot/elfin_robot/blob/noetic/elfin_description/urdf/elfin5.urdf.xacro), there's a part that mentions "elfin_dummy_gripper", I am assuming this the part I should edit? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411677/how-to-add-gripper-to-robot-arm-and-plan-according-to-the-end-effector-on-moveit/) by [reuge](https://answers.ros.org/users/135077/reuge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @reuge,

> Being new to Moveit, I am finding trouble to attach the gripper to the robot to be able to control it and plan accordingly.

What I would suggest is to first create xacro /urdf and join the gripper init. Have a look at [urdf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials)  Have a look at the tutorials for creating and joining the link.

> Looking at the robot's URDF, there's a part that mentions "elfin_dummy_gripper", I am assuming this the part I should edit? Any help is appreciated.

Yes, You are true you need to create and join the link with the end-effector.

> Being new to Moveit, I am finding trouble to attach the gripper to the robot to be able to control it and plan accordingly.

https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

You can have an option in move it while building the package in Add planning group.

https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html#step-4-add-planning-groups

feel free to drop a comment if any questions.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0